# concatenacion de variables en PHP

Tags: php

necesito guardar una cadena concatenada en la base de datos y resulta que solo me guarda cierta parte de la cadena, adjunto el codigo que estoy probando y un ejemplo de como se guarda la cadena en mi BD

```
public function save(){
    $save = $this->db->prepare("EXEC prc_tb_usuario_insert {$this->getNombre()}, {$this->getEmail()}, '{$this->getPassword()}', {$this->getEstado()}, {$this->getId_Perfil()}");
    $save->bindParam(1, $this->nombre, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
    $save->bindParam(2, $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
    $save->bindParam(3, $this->password, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
    $save->bindParam(4, $this->estado, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $save->bindParam(5, $this->id_perfil, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $save->execute();

    $result = false;
    if($save){
        $result = true;
        $tabla = TB_USER;
        $modulo = MOD_INS_USER;
        $ultimo_id = $this->db->lastInsertId();
        $valorAnterior = "Nuevo registro";
        $valorNuevo = "Nombre: " .$this->nombre. " - Email: " .$this->email. " - Password: " .$this->password. " - Estado: " .$this->estado. " - IdPerfil: " .$this->id_perfil;
        $valorNuevo = str_replace("'", "", $valorNuevo);
        $usuario = $_SESSION['identity']->email;
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        $audit_log = $this->db->prepare("EXEC prc_tb_auditLog_insertLog '$tabla', '$modulo', $ultimo_id, '$valorAnterior', '$valorNuevo', '$usuario', '$ip'");
        $audit_log->bindParam(1, $tabla, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
        $audit_log->bindParam(2, $modulo, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
        $audit_log->bindParam(3, $ultimo_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $audit_log->bindParam(4, $valorAnterior, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
        $audit_log->bindParam(5, $valorNuevo, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
        $audit_log->bindParam(6, $usuario, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
        $audit_log->bindParam(7, $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
        $audit_log->execute();
    }
    return $result; 
}
```

La variable $valorNuevo es la que necesito guardar en la BD y al momento de insertar los datos se me guarda así:

[image: CAMPO DE LA BD]

De todas formas le hice un var_dump a la variable y me muestra la cadena tal cual la quiero guardar en la BD, pero no entiendo porque no se guarda correctamente...

Adjunto imagenes del diseño de mis tablas y de lo que quisiera que se guarde en el campo valorNuevo:

Tabla usuario
[image: tbuser]

Tabla auditoria
[image: tbaudit]

Cadena a guardar
[image: string]

No logró entender porque la longitud de esta cadena es de 24000... será porque hago referencias a las variables del objeto mediante $this-> ???

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda :)

Saludos

Comment: ¿El tamaño de la columna valorNuevo en la base es suficiente para poder guardar esa cadena que concatenas?

Comment: Al parecer si, aunque me surge una duda con respecto a la longitud de las variables. Al rutear la variable $this->nombre, me arroja que tiene un lenght de 8000 y en mi BD ese campo es un NVARCHAR(200), pero aún asi se guarda correctamente al igual que los otros campos. Al rutear $valorNuevo, me da un lenght de 22000, entonces es algo confuso

Comment: Verifica la longitud de tu campo, puede ser que lo hayas dejado muy pequeño y solo se guarda hasta donde alcanza.

Comment: gracias por responder :) ya verifique todo y no es problema de longitud

Comment: Cómo que tienes un campo de 200 y guarda correctamente 8000???? Por favor, incluye en tu pregunta datos de prueba y la definición de la tabla.

Comment: es extraño, al hacer un var_dump($this->nombre); me arroja que es un string(8000), en otras funciones de mi sistema, agrego esta misma variable a mis BD donde especifico el nombre como un NVARCHAR(200), al igual que los demás campos, y se lográn insertar correctamente...
Agregaré más imagenes

Answer (score 0):

Quizas a mas de alguno le podrá ayudar como solucione mi problema, resulta que estaba definiendo una constante de PDO con un maximo de 4000 caracteres, desconozco el porque al medir la longitud de cualquier variable que pasa por el bindParam de PDO, me arroja un total de 8000 caracteres, cuando en realidad eran 10 o 20 por dar un ejemplo, asi que elimine esas constantes y ya me arrojaba la longitud exacta de la cadena y me guarda los datos correctamente en la BD.

Gracias por sus comentarios :D